Swift Predicate not working in Swift Data for String Array
In Swift Data I have a basic model
@Model class MovieSD {
 
    @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
    var genre: [String] = [String]()
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
    
}

I am trying to create predicates when fetching the data. Creating a predicate to search by title works as expected
let movieTitle = #Predicate<MovieSD> { movie in
    movie.title.contains("filterstring")
}

But when attempting to do the same for the String array
let movieGenre = #Predicate<MovieSD> { movie in
    movie.genre.contains("filterstring")
}

Results in a crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Similar approaches produce a different error and point to the likely issue.
let movieGenre2 = #Predicate<MovieSD> { movie in
    if movie.genre.contains(where: { $0 == "filterstring" }) {
         return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

Results in a crash with the error:
error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x281a96840> , Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquerySUBQUERY(genre, $$_local_1, $$_local_1 == "SciFi") with userInfo of (null)

or alternatively largely the same error for:
let movieGenre3 = #Predicate<MovieSD> { movie in
    movie.genre.filter { genre in
        return genre == "filterstring"
    }.count > 0
}

It seems that Swift Predicate should be able to make condition statements that would rely on SUBQUERY with NSPredicate. But in this case it doesn't seem too be working.
Naturally, I can use similar to the above to filter the array that is returned. But this seems inefficient. And it seems it should be possible to filter. Also, I want to avoid approaches that make the genres array into a @model Genre class.
Any help showing how to filter a String array with a predicate with Swift Data would be appreciated.

It doesn't look like this kind of predicate is supported currently so you are probably better of doing the filtering afterwards

If it suits your application you could store the genre in a different table and query on that.
@Model class Genre {
    @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
}
@Model class MovieSD {
    @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
    var genre = [Genre]()
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
    
}

This article can help explain why this happens.

if you use collections of value types, e.g. [String], SwiftData will save that directly inside a single property too. Right now it’s encoded as binary property list data, which means you can’t use the contents of your array in a predicate.


Hi thanks, the article link explained the reason it isn't working.
